# PHP: Persistent POST Variable Across Pagination Pages

Tags: php, pagination

After hours of trying to figure out why my pagination script wasn't working with my variables, I figured out with the help of some of you that my POST variables aren't being carried over from page to page as my data paginates.

Are sessions the best way to handle this type of scenario? For example, I have this:

```
session_start(); //start session
$_SESSION["formdata"] = $_POST['City']; //get form data input
$myvar = $_SESSION["formdata"]; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE City = \"$myvar\" LIMIT $start, $limit"; //query
```

Regardless, this does not seem to be working. The form data is displayed on the first page but any subsequent pages are blank. Thanks for the help and advice

**CODE:**

```html
session_start();
 
   
 
 include('sqlconnect.php'); // include your code to connect to DB.
mysql_select_db("barter") or die(mysql_error());
 $tbl_name="posts";  //your table name
 // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
 $adjacents = 3;
 
 /* 
    First get total number of rows in data table. 
    If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
 */
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
 $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
 $total_pages = $total_pages[num];
 
 /* Setup vars for query. */
 $targetpage = "fp2.php";  //your file name  (the name of this file)
 $limit = 3;         //how many items to show per page
 $page = $_GET['page'];
 if($page) 
  $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;    //first item to display on this page
 else
  $start = 0;        //if no page var is given, set start to 0
 
 /* Get data. */
 
 $_SESSION["formdata"] = $_GET['City'];
 $myvar = $_SESSION["formdata"];
 echo $myvar;
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE City = \"$myvar\" LIMIT $start, $limit";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 
 /* Setup page vars for display. */
 if ($page == 0) $page = 1;     //if no page var is given, default to 1.
 $prev = $page - 1;       //previous page is page - 1
 $next = $page + 1;       //next page is page + 1
 $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);  //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
 $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;      //last page minus 1
 
 /* 
  Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
  We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
 */
 $pagination = "";
 if($lastpage > 1)
 { 
  $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
  //previous button
  if ($page > 1) 
   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">previous</a>";
  else
   $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">previous</span>"; 
  
  //pages 
  if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
  { 
   for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
   {
    if ($counter == $page)
     $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
    else
     $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
   }
  }
  elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some
  {
   //close to beginning; only hide later pages
   if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))  
   {
    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
    {
     if ($counter == $page)
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
     else
      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
    }
    $pagination.= "...";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";  
   }
   //in middle; hide some front and some back
   elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
   {
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
    $pagination.= "...";
    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
    {
     if ($counter == $page)
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
     else
      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
    }
    $pagination.= "...";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";  
   }
   //close to end; only hide early pages
   else
   {
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
    $pagination.= "...";
    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
    {
     if ($counter == $page)
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
     else
      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
    }
   }
  }
  
  //next button
  if ($page < $counter - 1) 
   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next</a>";
  else
   $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next</span>";
  $pagination.= "</div>\n";  
 }
?>

 <?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
 
  echo ('<br>');
 echo '<div style="margin-left:52%;">';
 echo '<div style="  width:100%; . " id="Posts">';
 
 echo '<h3>' . $row["Title"] .'</h3>';
 echo 'posted by:' . $row["Name"] . "<br/>";
 echo 'Posted On:' . $row["Time"] . "<br/>";
 
 echo $row["postname"] . "<br/>";
 
 echo $row["Post"] . "<br/>";
 echo ('<a href=http://brightstardetailers.ddns.net/Barter/' . $row["postname"] . '.php' . '>Full Post</a>' . "<br/>");

 
 echo '</div>';
 echo '</div>';
 
  }
 ?>

<?=$pagination?>
```

Comment: How come you aren't doing one page that calls itself all the time? That would help.

Comment: I am. But the pagination part of the script appends the page number to the end of the URL and then refreshes the page

Comment: If it's appending a URL then are you using `$_GET`?

Comment: I've substituted my POST variables for GET but I see the same results. Only the first data set is shown and the rest of the set is blank when I try to paginate

Comment: Post your code and we'll figure it out...

Comment: So on every page load, you do `$_SESSION["formdata"] = $_POST['City'];`, right? If `$_POST` is blank when you click on a pagination link (which was your original problem), then you're overwriting the data in `$_SESSION` on each page load, bringing you back to your original problem.

Comment: Yeah, but if the user wants to select a different city the data needs to be overwritten. I'm just not sure why this script refuses to paginate if I'm using a POST variable rather than a static value

Comment: Don't have time to run it locally but: `$page` is first set by `$page = $_GET['page'];` though later you have a line that goes `if ($page == 0) $page = 1;` in case the GET variable `page` wasn't set. However, if `page` is missing or otherwise unset in the initial request, `($page == 0)` evaluates to false so doesn't `$page` remain unset? Although I assume you would have seen an undefined index error if so...

Comment: Oops, my bad -- an unset variable is apparently loosely equal to 0 so ($page == 0) is true.

Comment: Did any of these folks solve your issue or are you still stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paginator loads up a new page. It does not forward the POST request on to the new page load, so when the page loads, `$_POST` is empty. There won't be a really great way of populating `$_POST` via a regular web link. You would have to either submit a form or do pagination via AJAX instead.

I think the easiest thing for you to do would be to skip using sessions for this, and instead wrap your pagination links in a `<form>`. Populate hidden inputs in this form with your `$_POST` data and use JavaScript to listen for a click event on each of the pagination links. When one of those links is clicked, either populate another hidden input with the page number (if you want to pass the page number in via POST), or modify the `action` attribute of the form to include the page number in the GET part of the URL. Then submit the form with JavaScript.

This would make it so that your POST data is populated after clicking the pagination link, in addition to the new page you want. No need to store stuff globally in the session.

Comment: Same issue and in my situation, I am thinking better option to move to _GET and add params to the pagination urls...